# Errors while trying to load data from MySql

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I am working/learning how to mvc a project structure. I have a database connector, a registry class, a model and an application model. I have all these in one place to check it working. The problem is I get these three errors when I execute.

```
<?php

class db
{
    protected $conn;
    protected $host, $username, $password, $database;

    public function __construct($host, $username, $password, $database)
    {
        $this->conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database)
        OR die("There was a problem connecting to the database");

        return true;
    }

    public function query($sql)
    {
        $result = $this->conn->query($sql);
        if (!$result) {
            die('Invalid query:');
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function escape($value)
    {
        return $this->conn->real_escape_string($value);
    }

    public function countAffected()
    {
        return $this->conn->affected_rows;
    }

    public function getLastId()
    {
        return $this->conn->insert_id;
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->conn->close()
        OR die("Problem disconnecting from the database");
    }
}

final class registry
{
    private $data = array();

    public function get($key)
    {
        return (isset($this->data[$key]) ? $this->data[$key] : null);
    }

    public function set($key, $value)
    {
        $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function has($key)
    {
        return isset($this->data[$key]);
    }
}

abstract class Model
{
    protected $registry;

    public function __construct($registry)
    {
        $this->registry = $registry;  // Undefined variable: registry
    }

    public function __get($key)
    {
        return $this->registry->get($key);
    }

    public function __set($key, $value)
    {
        $this->registry->set($key, $value);
    }

}

class MemberModel extends Model
{
    public function getMember()
    {
        $result = $this->query("SELECT * FROM members"); //Call to undefined method MemberModel::query()
        return $result;
    }
}

// DB
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'pcaframework');

$registry = new registry();

// Database
$db = new db(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
$registry->set('db', $db);

$membermodel = new MemberModel(); //Missing argument 1 for Model::__construct()

$allMembers = $membermodel->getMember();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($allMembers)) {
    echo "First Name: " . $row['name'] . "<br />";
    echo "Last Name: " . $row['email'] . "<br />";
    echo "<hr />";
}
```

- Missing argument 1 for Model::__construct(), called on $membermodel = new MemberModel();
- Undefined variable: registry
- Call to undefined method MemberModel::query()

I have commented the error in the code to mark exactly where the error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to:

```
$result = $this->query("SELECT * FROM members"); //Call to undefined method MemberModel::query()
```

Replace with:

```
$result = $this->conn->query("SELECT * FROM members");
```

You just forget the "->conn->".

Solution to:

```
$this->registry = $registry;  // Undefined variable: registry
```

And

```
$membermodel = new MemberModel(); //Missing argument 1 for Model::__construct()
```

Just replace this last with the $registry var as a parameter to the new class:

```
$membermodel = new MemberModel($registry);
```

You're calling the constructor, that needs a parameter, but you're not refering that parameter.

Comment: Olivera, solved all three problems but gave me a new one, Call to a member function get() on string on abstract class model > function __get($key) > return $this->registry->get($key); //

Comment: Try replacing the function "get" on registry class by:

public function get($key)
{
        return (isset($this->data[$key])) ? $this->data[$key] : null;
}

Comment: Please let me know the code where "$membermodel->get($key);" or "$registry->get($key);" is called.

Comment: I think I found the solution. Please search for "$membermodel->get($key);" and if there exists a call like it, replace by "$membermodel->__get($key);".